# Equivalent of SSE unpacklo_ps/unpackhi_ps in AVX (for doubles)

Tags: c, sse, avx

In SSE, if I have a 128-bit register containing 4 floats i.e.

```
A = a b c d ('a','b','c','d' are floats and 'A' is a 128-bit SSE register)
```

and

```
B = e f g h
```

then if I want

```
C = a e b f
```

I can simply do:

```
C = _mm_unpacklo_ps(A,B);
```

Similarly if I want

```
D = c g d h
```

I can do:

```
D = _mm_unpackhi_ps(A,B);
```

If I have an AVX register containing doubles, is it possible to do the same with a single instruction?

Based on how these intrinsics work, I know that I can't use `_mm256_unpacklo_pd()`, `_mm256_shuffle_pd()`, `_mm256_permute2f128_pd()` or `_mm256_blend_pd()`. Is there any instruction apart from these that I can use or do I have to use a combination of the above instructions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way that I can think of is the following:

```
A1 = _mm256_unpacklo_pd(A,B);
A2 = _mm256_unpackhi_pd(A,B);

C = _mm256_permute2f128_pd(A1,A2,0x20);
D = _mm256_permute2f128_pd(A1,A2,0x31);
```

If anyone has a better solution, please do post below.

Comment: I don't think you're going to do much better than that. Since you want values to cross the 128-bit boundary in the process, I think you're going to have to use one of the 128-bit permute functions. That's just one of the limitations of AVX. AVX2, which is supported in the upcoming Haswell family of x86 processors, is a bit more flexible, as it will support anywhere-to-anywhere permutation operations, but I'm still not sure if it will yield a shorter sequence of instructions.